# Ralink MT7601U driver Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: 14.04, wireless

I am trying to get this wifi dongle working on a BBB with Ubuntu 14.04.

The adapter can be seen

```
lsusb 
Bus 001 Device 002: 148f:7601 Ralink Technology, Corp. MT7601U Wireless Adapter
```

I have followed multiple tutorials on trying to get this too work 90% of which point to a dead git `https://github.com/porjo/mt7601.git`

If I try other drivers or the drivers that came with the dongle I get

```
make -C /lib/modules/4.1.13-ti-r36/build SUBDIRS=/home/ubuntu/mt7610u/os/linux modules
make[1]: Entering directory `/lib/modules/4.1.13-ti-r36/build'
make[1]: *** No rule to make target `modules'.  Stop.
make[1]: Leaving directory `/lib/modules/4.1.13-ti-r36/build'
make: *** [LINUX] Error 2
```

MESG shows

```
[ 2788.099742] mt7601u: probe of 1-1:1.0 failed with error -110
[ 2788.111390] usb 1-1: USB disconnect, device number 97
[ 2788.408545] usb 1-1: new high-speed USB device number 98 using musb-hdrc
[ 2788.559661] usb 1-1: New USB device found, idVendor=148f, idProduct=7601
[ 2788.559697] usb 1-1: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=3
[ 2788.559718] usb 1-1: Product: 802.11 n WLAN
[ 2788.559735] usb 1-1: Manufacturer: MediaTek
[ 2788.559751] usb 1-1: SerialNumber: 1.0
[ 2788.678411] usb 1-1: reset high-speed USB device number 98 using musb-hdrc
[ 2788.821754] mt7601u 1-1:1.0: ASIC revision: 76010001 MAC revision: 76010500
[ 2788.823836] mt7601u 1-1:1.0: Firmware Version: 0.1.00 Build: 7640 Build time: 201302052146____
[ 2790.047264] mt7601u 1-1:1.0: Warning: unsupported EEPROM version 0d
[ 2790.047327] mt7601u 1-1:1.0: EEPROM ver:0d fae:00
[ 2790.212543] mt7601u 1-1:1.0: Error: RX urb failed:-71
[ 2790.220922] mt7601u 1-1:1.0: Error: submit URB dir:128 ep:1 failed:-19
[ 2790.253854] usb 1-1: USB disconnect, device number 98
```

Note `device number` keeps incrementing, not sure if that is a clue.

Love any suggestions!

**More Info**

```
modinfo mt7601u
filename:       /lib/modules/4.4.6-ti-r15/kernel/drivers/net/wireless/mediatek/mt7601u/mt7601u.ko
license:        GPL
firmware:       mt7601u.bin
alias:          usb:v7392p7710d*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*in*
alias:          usb:v2A5Fp1000d*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*in*
alias:          usb:v2955p1001d*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*in*
alias:          usb:v2955p0001d*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*in*
alias:          usb:v2717p4106d*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*in*
alias:          usb:v2001p3D04d*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*in*
alias:          usb:v148Fp760Dd*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*in*
alias:          usb:v148Fp760Cd*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*in*
alias:          usb:v148Fp760Bd*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*in*
alias:          usb:v148Fp760Ad*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*in*
alias:          usb:**v148Fp7601d** *dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*in*
alias:          usb:v13D3p3434d*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*in*
alias:          usb:v13D3p3431d*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*in*
alias:          usb:v0E8Dp760Bd*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*in*
alias:          usb:v0E8Dp760Ad*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*in*
alias:          usb:v0B05p17D3d*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*in*
depends:        mac80211,cfg80211
intree:         Y
vermagic:       4.4.6-ti-r15 SMP mod_unload modversions ARMv7 thumb2 p2v8
```

Comment: [https://github.com/kuba-moo/mt7601u](https://github.com/kuba-moo/mt7601u) I think it has better quality, since it is merged into Linux kernel mainline. Though from the module name in your message, it looks like you are using it. Maybe you need to clean up all works done in all your previous tries, then retry it. Or upgrade your kernel to 4.2, which native supports your dongle.

Comment: My kernel is 4.4.6 and the module is loading but doesn't seem to be associated  when the dongle is plugged in.  I have reloaded so starting fresh

Answer (score 0):

Hours of chasing my tail a brought another dongle and it worked immediately.